# table collides with section content in latex

Tags: tables, formatting

I am writing a research paper in where I have to write a table in latex. My Code in latex is as follows:

```
 \begin{table}[!t]
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r}
    \hline
    cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
    \hline
    cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
    \hline
    cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}  
} 
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{table}
```

But the table is now colliding with section content as described in the screenshot. How can I get rid of this?

[image]

Also, I want to center my caption of table which does not work here. How can I do this ?

Comment: Remove the makebox command. To horizontally center the table within its column of text, you can use \centering instead.

Comment: Not directly related but eplace positioning specifier `[!t]` with `[htb]`.

Comment: The `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{` is completely wrong here it is adding a word space (from the newline after `{`) to the left of the table and then centering the tabular in the width of the page when your image suggestes that you have a two column docuemnt and this is a single column float. Just remove  the whole line and use `\centering` to centre the tabular within the column

Comment: I want to place the table in center of table. If I remove \noindent\makebox then the table does not reside in center of table.

Comment: That is why they ask you to use `\centering`. The proper way to center a tabular is the following `\begin{table}[htp] \centering <tabular and stuff> \end{table}`